# Special coffee served in Malaysia (or India)

Tags: coffee, indian-cuisine

When I was in Malaysia an Indian friend offer to me a coffee, It tasted really nice and kinda unique. I'm not sure if that coffee was unique from Malaysia or recipe from India. The store where I got those was just a regular hawker around Johor Bahru, Johor, Malaysia.

It looked something like this: [image]

I would be really happy if you recognize or know what I am describing.

Comment: [Indian Filter Coffee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_filter_coffee) is pretty much the only famous, unique coffee from India. It looks similar but with less milk or cream.

Comment: That looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_coffee, but although that's found in a lot of europe and all of the middle east I didn't think it went that far east.

Comment: +1 for vwiggins guess of Turkish, but I think we'll need more information to make a solid guess.   Any details you can add?  Like, more specific than "nice and unique"?  Or, if you saw it made (with what method) etc ...

Comment: @user1190992, I think that's pretty close guess. I'll have to find some shops that sells this locally to really find out.

Comment: @vwiggins, the turkish coffee looks very thick or is just on the picture. Thanks though.

Comment: @hunter2, Yes, sorry for that.  I don't have any additional information I can add anymore, I can just rely on my taste bud whether that's the coffee or not.

Answer (score 3):

There's a very specific coffee culture to singapore and malaysia with a ton of varients.

Lets start with the basics

This is a kopi o

[image]

By default, any drink you order is *hot*. This is *plain black coffee* and any coffee order you make at a *kopi tiam* will likely be a varient on this.

You might note that its somewhat darker than your example I'd assume this means it has some condensed milk added to it. A quick google search suggested two varients.

[image]

kopi 'c' - or coffee with (evaporated) milk

[image: enter link description here]

kopi nai (with condensed milk and sugar) -

The former looks a bit too light, though exact mixes vary. Chances are its one of these.

That said, there's two distinct regional styles of roasting - typical coffee roasting is done with a hint of sugar and margarine, and roasted VERY dark. There's also a style called white coffee that just uses margarine that's supposed to be famous in ipoh.

Answer (score 1):

the coffee which you pointed out is [nanyang coffee](http://www.foodspotting.com/places/133454-bedok-interchange-hawker-centre-/items/360074-nanyang-coffee),its actually traditional coffee in singapore

Comment: nanyang coffee might be the name of the store.

Comment: "Nanyang" is "South [China] Sea" in Chinese, and the label is commonly used for all sorts of traditional but Chinese-influenced dishes in Singapore and Malaysia.

Answer (score 0):

This is "kampung coffee", or "[kopi-o](http://www.saikee.com/products.htm)". The linked site says that it is roasted with margarine and sugar.